# how to put selected item in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating a dropdown list in php. how can i put the selected item when someone selects an item.

my php code:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
            <select name="app" id="dropdown" value="" onchange="this.form.submit()"  ><option>--select-app--</option>
                <?php 
                $sql="select * from application";
                $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("ereor selecting app ".mysqli_error($con));
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $selected = $row['name'];
                    echo "<option id=". $row['id']."value = ".$row['id'].">".$row['name']."</option>";
                }

                echo "</select>";

                ?>
```

i want this: if I select an item it will show it as selected. how can I do this

Comment: jQuery is the best way. But you haven't explained how you want it to be displayed or anything. Can you shed some light?

Comment: how to use jquery? i have a dropdown list. and I want if a user click an item then the dropdown list close and show the item selected. how can i do this. it is only showing the "--select-app--" after it closes which is my first option.

Comment: So let me make sure i understand. You want to display the selected item elsewhere after it's been chosen from the list?

Comment: i want to show the item as the selected item. i mean when the list closes it will keep showing the selected item

Comment: But where, in the list or elsewhere on the page?

Comment: You'll probably have to use jQuery to modify the list to put the selected item to the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in php like

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
   <select name="app" id="dropdown" value="" onchange="this.form.submit()"  >
       <option>--select-app--</option>
   <?php 
       $sql="select * from application";
       $result=mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("ereor selecting app ".mysqli_error($con));
       $selected_val = $_POST['app']; //Should be $_GET, $_POST, $_SESSION whatever your selected value is
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
       {
           if(trim($row['id']) == trim($selected_val))   //<== Change this line
                $selected = 'selected="selected"';
           else
                $selected = '';
           echo '<option id="'. $row['id'].'" value="'.$row['id'].'" '. $selected.'>'. $row['name'] .'</option>';
          //^Change this line
       }

       echo "</select>";

      ?>
```

In jQuery you can do it like

```
 $('#dropdown').val('<?php echo "My val"; //The value goes here ?>');
```

Comment: this solution is working but. there is a problem. onchange="this.form.submit(). it is working when i remove this. i want to submit the form too and keep the value of selected item in the dropdown menu also

Comment: It should retain the selected value if you use `$selected_val = isset($_POST['app'])?$_POST['app']:'';`

Comment: not it is not retaining the value in the dropdown list. after the form submission. it is showing ---select app--

Comment: I have changed 2 lines in the answer, please make the changes and test. It should work now :) (read the comments)

Comment: i want to give you a treat. thanks man :) i was trying this from the morning. thanks . thanks. thanks. :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean you want to retain the selection after the form is submitted, you can do this inside the while loop:

```
$selected = (isset($_POST['app']) && $_POST['app'] == $row['id'] ? 'selected' : '');
echo "<option id=".$row['id']." value = ".$row['id']." ".$selected.">".$row['name']."</option>";
```

Comment: @new_stacky Then I must not understand what you want to do. This will do what it says in the answer - retain the selected value after the form has been submitted

Comment: ok. this is working fine. but "onchange" is creating problem. the form is submitted itself. but after submission it is not retaining the value. thanks for the above solution btw. and now i have a different problem